# Bash get the number if integer indexed elements in array

Tags: arrays, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Lets say you have an array with both integer indexes and string indexes like so...

Edit... Note: This block will be in a loop in my app

```
declare -A arr
arr[${#arr[@]}]=someVal1
arr[${#arr[@]}]=someVal2
arr[someBool]=true
arr[someOtherString]="Some Text"
arr[${#arr[@]}]=someVal3
```

Now lets say I want to compare the number of array items for some reason...

```
[ "${#arr[@]}" = 5 ] && echo "there are 5 array items";
```

output...

```
there are 5 array items
```

Ok thats all and good but lets take a look at our array

```
declare -p arr

exit
```

output...

```
declare -A arr='([someBool]="true" [someOtherString]="Some Text" 
[0]="someVal1" [1]="someVal2" [4]="someVal3" )'
```

Notice that the integer indexes go 0,1,4

So my Question is what should replace

```
arr[${#arr[@]}]=
```

so that the integer array indexes work out properly? (0,1,2)

Edit...  Temp Solution Based on Henk Langeveld's input... Temp because it should be able to edit an array passed to it not just edit a global array statically.

```
#!/bin/bash
getArrIntIndexNum(){
    local x=0
    for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
        [[ $i =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]] && x=$((x+1))
    done
    echo $x
}

declare -A arr
arr[$(getArrIntIndexNum)]=someVal1
arr[$(getArrIntIndexNum)]=someVal2
arr[someBool]=true
arr[someOtherString]="Some Text"
arr[$(getArrIntIndexNum)]=someVal3

declare -p arr
```

output...

declare -A arr='([someBool]="true" [someOtherString]="Some Text" [0]="someVal1" [1]="someVal2" [2]="someVal3" )'

Comment: I've slightly modified the `declare -p` output, as if there's a right margin.  The result can still be interpreted by bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding a warning here: You should really split this structure, because what you're trying to do (are told to do) is mixing two different data types.

Bash and ksh93 support both ordered *arrays* (with an integer index) and unordered *associative* arrays (mappings keyed with string values).

So, the thing called:

> an array with both integer indexes and string indexes

is actually an associative array, with strings for keys.

When updating a map, you can only add or remove elements by key.

Associative arrays are optimised to find any random key, while arrays are optimised for access by offset, and looping through an index.  Emulating one with the other will incur greater complexity, will be harder to maintain, and will degrade performance.

---

When all you need is an ordered list in either ksh or bash, use

```
typeset -a list=( value1 value2 )
```

In bash, you can substitute `declare` for `typeset`.  In older versions of `ksh` you 
may need to use `set -A list value1 value2`

Comment: so I would have to loop though keys incriminating a var if key is integer?

Comment: Don't know what's meant with *incriminating*, but I think you've got the gist.  You might want to maintain a separate list if you need to count things, though.

Comment: opps typo... incrementing like x=$x+1;... OK thanks for your help!

Comment: Clarified the alternate syntax for ordered lists after you accepted. You may want to review.